# Influx to SQL Server connectivity

Tags: sql-server, influxdb

I need to build connectivity between `Influx` and a SQL Server database to transfer data from `Influx` to SQL Server periodically.

Ideally I would like to have a stored procedure in SQL Server which connects with `Influx` and gets the required data. This procedure will be scheduled using a SQL Server Agent Job.

Will appreciate any answers regarding the possibilities to achieve the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the [SSIS Data Streaming Destination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/data-streaming-destination?view=sql-server-2017).  This will enable you to have a view in SQL Server that returns the results of running a package.

An SSIS package, in turn, can connect to data sources without loading drivers in the SQL Server process, or can run custom .NET code to interop, or orchestrate running external processes that generate files, and then return the file contents.

So whatever the mechanism of data extract from `influxdb` turns out to be, an SSIS package using the Data Streaming Destination can be an adapter for you to read that data from inside SQL Server.